# Isql import with big file

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, isql

When I try to import big SQL file with isql, I have strange error

```
"c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\isql.exe" -b -e -i d:\ImportSQL.sql localhost:D:\ImportDB.gdb -user SYSDBA-password masterkey
```

[image]

```
Statement ailed, SQLSTATE = 42000
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -104
-Token unknow -line 2, column 1
-F_ID
At line 2 in file d:\ImportSQL.SQL
```

When I import with FireDac (Delphi component) or IBExpert IDE: it works well.

Is there a way to import big file with isql ?

script contains only lines (UPDATE) like this :

```sql
UPDATE Client set ITF_ID=1093504349 where ITF_ID=1335867821;
UPDATE Client set ITF_ID=1093454349 where ITF_ID=1335802286;
UPDATE Client set ITF_ID=1093404349 where ITF_ID=1335736751;
UPDATE Client set ITF_ID=1093354349 where ITF_ID=1335671216;
UPDATE Client set ITF_ID=1093304349 where ITF_ID=1335605681;
UPDATE Client set ITF_ID=1093254349 where ITF_ID=1335540146;
```

Comment: The problem might be the double semi-colon at the end of the last statement displayed. Other than that, you would really need to show more context. I suggest that you remove lines from the script until it stops failing, and then check what that line does (in isolation).

Comment: @Mark all lines are similar but there is a lot.

Comment: As far as I know size of the script is not a factor, so it probably is something like the double semi-colon in your screenshot, or something like whitespace between `IT` and `F_ID` for one of those statements.

Comment: I strongly suggest you look at the line **after** the displayed line.

Comment: In fact there is no linebreak after ;